# Display category multi-select with Advanced Custom Felds

Tags: advanced-custom-fields

I'm trying to have a multi-select where users can select which categories they want in a template. The functionality i want is similar to the "Select" field type but only pulling through categories to display NOT posts of those categories.

I've got the multi-select working fine and high-lighting the selected options of that page but in the templates, the values are not displayed using:

---

```
<?php var_dump(get_field('featured_tags')); ?>
```

The full code of the custom field type below:

```
<?php

class acf_Section extends acf_Field
{

    /*--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    *
    *   Constructor
    *
    *   @author Elliot Condon
    *   @since 1.0.0
    *   @updated 2.2.0
    *
    *-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

    function __construct($parent)
    {
        parent::__construct($parent);

        $this->name = 'section';
        $this->title = __("Section",'acf');

        // filters (for all fields with choices)
        add_filter('acf_save_field-select', array($this, 'acf_save_field'));

    }



    /*--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    *
    *   create_field
    *
    *   @author Elliot Condon
    *   @since 2.0.5
    *   @updated 2.2.0
    *
    *-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

    function create_field($field)
    {
        // vars
        $defaults = array(
            'value'         =>  array(),
            'multiple'      =>  0,
            'allow_null'    =>  0,
            'choices'       =>  array(),
            'optgroup'      =>  0,
        );

        $field = array_merge($defaults, $field);


        // no choices
        if(empty($field['choices']))
        {
            echo '<p>' . __("No choices to choose from",'acf') . '</p>';
            return false;
        }


        // multiple select
        $multiple = '';
        if( $field['multiple'] )
        {
            // create a hidden field to allow for no selections
            echo '<input type="hidden" name="' . $field['name'] . '" />';

            $multiple = ' multiple="multiple" size="5" ';
            $field['name'] .= '[]';
        }


        // html
        echo '<select id="' . $field['id'] . '" class="' . $field['class'] . '" name="' . $field['name'] . '" ' . $multiple . ' >';

        $args = array(
            'orderby' => 'name',
            'parent' => 0,
            'taxonomy' => 'sections',
        );

        $categories = get_categories($args);

        $field['choices'] = '';

        foreach($categories as $cat) {

            $selected = '';
            if(is_array($field['value']) && in_array($cat->term_id, $field['value']))
            {
                // 2. If the value is an array (multiple select), loop through values and check if it is selected
                $selected = 'selected="selected"';
            }

            echo '<option value="'.$cat->term_id.'" '.$selected.'>'.$cat->name.'</option>';
        }

        echo '</select>';
    }


    /*--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    *
    *   create_options
    *
    *   @author Elliot Condon
    *   @since 2.0.6
    *   @updated 2.2.0
    *
    *-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

    function create_options($key, $field)
    {

    }

    function update_value($post_id, $field, $value)
    {
        // save value
        parent::update_value($post_id, $field, $value);
    }


    /*--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    *
    *   pre_save_field
    *   - called just before saving the field to the database.
    *
    *   @author Elliot Condon
    *   @since 2.2.0
    *
    *-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

    function acf_save_field( $field )
    {
        // vars
        $defaults = array(
            'choices'   =>  '',
        );

        $args = array(
            'orderby' => 'name',
            'parent' => 0,
            'taxonomy' => 'sections',
        );

        $categories = get_categories($args);

        $field = array_merge($defaults, $field);

        foreach($categories as $cat) {
            $field['choices'] .= $cat->term_id.' : '.$cat->name."\n";
        }


        // check if is array. Normal back end edit posts a textarea, but a user might use update_field from the front end
        if( is_array( $field['choices'] ))
        {
            return $field;
        }


        // vars
        $new_choices = array();


        // explode choices from each line
        if( $field['choices'] )
        {
            // stripslashes ("")
            $field['choices'] = stripslashes_deep($field['choices']);

            if(strpos($field['choices'], "\n") !== false)
            {
                // found multiple lines, explode it
                $field['choices'] = explode("\n", $field['choices']);
            }
            else
            {
                // no multiple lines!
                $field['choices'] = array($field['choices']);
            }


            // key => value
            foreach($field['choices'] as $choice)
            {
                if(strpos($choice, ' : ') !== false)
                {
                    $choice = explode(' : ', $choice);
                    $new_choices[trim($choice[0])] = trim($choice[1]);
                }
                else
                {
                    $new_choices[trim($choice)] = trim($choice);
                }
            }
        }



        // update choices
        $field['choices'] = $new_choices;


        // return updated field
        return $field;

    }


    /*--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    *
    *   get_value_for_api
    *
    *   @author Elliot Condon
    *   @since 3.1.2
    *
    *-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

    function get_value_for_api($post_id, $field)
    {
        $value = parent::get_value($post_id, $field);

        if($value == 'null')
        {
            $value = false;
        }

        return $value;
    }

}

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the [Multiple Category Selection](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/multiple-category-selection-widget/) plugin will do what you're looking to do. Worth a look anyway...